# It is possible to use Java to handle an external window menu?

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I wonder if it's possible to get an object representation of a menu bar from an external window with a java program ?

My final goal is to make a java app which can retrieve the text on a menu from another window when we click on it.
I heared about Java JNA to handle windows but i didn't find a way to get the menu bar.

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: It depends on how the other program is implemented. Start by looking at UI Automation.

Comment: The other program could be anything, from word to another java program. I start looking for UI Automation now. Thanks

Comment: If that other program could be anything at all, then your task is impossible.

Comment: It's what i was thinking, thanks for your fast answer.